# Powershell Test-NetConnection "Name resolution of [domain] failed" error

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I'm trying to connect to connect to an Azure Files share using Powershell, but it's failing, so am going through each command to try and locate the issue.  Searching online, it seems that I need to verify port 445 is open (which my Bitdefender firewall has been configured to allow).

I ran this command in Azure Powershell to test:

```
Test-NetConnection -Port 445 -ComputerName https://myazurefileshare.file.core.windows.net
```

The error was:

> WARNING: Name resolution of https://myazurefileshare.file.core.windows.net failed

I then opted for something more generic, using port 80 as a test (sorry Microsoft):

```
Test-NetConnection -Port 80 -ComputerName https://www.microsoft.com
```

Surprisingly, this also failed:

> WARNING: Name resolution of https://www.microsoft.com failed

I'm new to Powershell, so please excuse any RTFM oversights.  However, can anyone please shed any light on this?  I'm simply trying to **verify that port 445 is open**.

Comment: have you tried `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName "www.google.com"` from that server and checked that issue is not related to the dns server . 
You can assign 8.8.8.8 as a secondary dns in the server and see what is the output.

Comment: Okay thanks.  That command has worked okay

Comment: Can you test it on a machine within your local network ?

Comment: So that means there is no issue on the command or the connection. It is pure the site that you are using and the corresponding DNS resolution. Try adding an A record in the resolv.conf  or adding the entry in the hosts file and see.

Also ignore the warning that you are getting for microsoft.com -- that is a separate thing. Could be a microsoft forwarder thing.

Comment: The reason for the warning is when name resolution is provided by root hints, Windows Server 2008 DNS and Windows Server 2008 R2 DNS Servers may fail to resolve queries for names in certain top-level domains. When this happens, the problem will continue until the DNS Server cache is cleared or the DNS Server service is restarted.

Comment: Okay I've found a solution, and will post an answer after my meeting finishes in a couple of hours.  Thank you kindly for your assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original error properly happens because you have typed the wrong format of the parameter `-ComputerName` for use [Test-NetConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=win10-ps#optional-parameters). The `ComputerName` specifies the Domain Name System (DNS) name or IP address of the target computer.

In this case, the computer name should be an FQDN of your storage account. So you could use `Test-NetConnection -Port 445 -ComputerName somestoragexxx.file.core.windows.net` to verify the port 445.

Test result on my side, name resolution works successfully but TCP 445 connection has a failure.
[image]

The same test result as [the script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Troubleshooting-tool-for-a9fa1fe5#content) MS provided.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the port was open after all (so cue another question later...).  Microsoft have a troubleshooting script which is way more powerful at mounting the drive than the default script available within the Azure Files "Connect" link, see [Troubleshooting tool for Azure Files mounting errors on Windows](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Troubleshooting-tool-for-a9fa1fe5#content).

I saved **AzFileDiagnostics.ps1** to my desktop for the purposes of the following example.  Sadly it won't run without unblocking first because it's not digitally signed, so the full Powershell script I had to run was:

```
> Unblock-File -Path "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\AzFileDiagnostics.ps1"
> C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\AzFileDiagnostics.ps1
```

The script then presents various parameter prompts that you need to complete, such as the storage name, etc.  However, the key check is the port check - this returned okay for me:

> ```
> ======Validate Storage Account Name resolution
>
> [OK]: Storage Account Name myazurefileshare.file.core.windows.net is
> resolved to 51.140.232.124
>
> ======Validate port 445 reachability over Storage Account IP 51.140.232.124
>
> [OK]: Connection attempt succeeds -  Port is open
>
> [OK]: Validation steps do not return any errors
> ```